# Dataframe to custom Dictionary and vice-versa

Tags: python, pandas

I have a use case of converting dataframe to dictionary and return back dictionary to same data frame format. I was able to figure out how to convert the dataframe to required format of dictionary I wanted. But, vice versa I got stuck.

```
>>> df
    C1 C2 C3
0  foo  H  C
1  foo  D  E
2  bar  F  G
3  bar  E  E
4  foo  F  G

>>> df['temp'] = df[['C2','C3']].apply(lambda x: {x[0]:x[1]},axis=1)
>>> df
    C1 C2 C3          temp
0  foo  H  C  {u'H': u'C'}
1  foo  D  E  {u'D': u'E'}
2  bar  F  G  {u'F': u'G'}
3  bar  E  E  {u'E': u'E'}
4  foo  F  G  {u'F': u'G'}

>>> df.groupby('C1')['temp'].apply(list)
C1
bar                  [{u'F': u'G'}, {u'E': u'E'}]
foo    [{u'H': u'C'}, {u'D': u'E'}, {u'F': u'G'}]
Name: temp, dtype: object

>>> df.groupby('C1')['temp'].apply(list).to_dict()
{'foo': [{'H': 'C'}, {'D': 'E'}, {'F': 'G'}], 'bar': [{'F': 'G'}, {'E': 'E'}]}
```

After process I will get dictionary something similar and little change in values. so I wanted to reconstruct the data frame back.

When I reconstruct,

```
>>>pd.series({'foo': [{'H': 'C'}, {'D': 'E'}, {'F': 'G'}], 
                           'bar': [{'F': 'G'}, {'E': 'E'}]})

bar                  [{u'F': u'G'}, {u'E': u'E'}]
foo    [{u'H': u'C'}, {u'D': u'E'}, {u'F': u'G'}]
dtype: object
```

I have no clue after this..

Comment: do you want the same order as original?

Comment: Order doesn't matter but same format.

Comment: The usual comment with issues like this: why can't you use a groupby object (staying in pandas) and do the same thing. Most of the time python's duck typing will mean your code will work (or can be tweaked to work) with this, but will be faster for access and use a smaller amount of memory.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I would be using this data as one of the input in pyspark and would need be a normal python object since pandas is not in all nodes of cluster. So, staying in pandas is little difficult. Another solution I found is pickling numpy, scipy and pandas along with code, that might be kind of hard if something goes wrong it will take days to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your modified dictionary `d`, you can use a list comprehension to regenerate a new dataframe.

```
df_col_names = df.columns[:3]  # Use the first three column names to match output.
>>> pd.DataFrame([(c1, sub_dict.keys()[0], sub_dict.values()[0]) 
                  for c1 in d.keys()
                  for sub_dict in d[c1]], 
                 columns=df_col_names)

    C1 C2 C3
0  foo  H  C
1  foo  D  E
2  foo  F  G
3  bar  F  G
4  bar  E  E
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df_dict = df.groupby('C1')[['C2', 'C3']].apply(lambda x: {k:v for k, v in x.to_records(index=False) for l in x}).to_dict()

{'foo': {'D': 'E', 'F': 'G', 'H': 'C'}, 'bar': {'E': 'E', 'F': 'G'}}

new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for k, v in df_dict.items():
    for v1, v2 in v.items():
        new_df = pd.concat([new_df, pd.DataFrame(columns=[k], data=[v1, v2], index=['C2', 'C3'])], axis=1)

print(new_df.T.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'C1'}))

    C1 C2 C3
0  bar  F  G
1  bar  E  E
2  foo  F  G
3  foo  D  E
4  foo  H  C
```

Comment: Thanks, but you didn't actually convert it to dictionary. I cannot access pandas data frame, since it will in cluster. It has to be standard python object.

Comment: Sorry, misread your question, updated accordingly. Let me know if this doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
dict = {'foo': [{'H': 'C'}, {'D': 'E'}, {'F': 'G'}], 'bar': [{'F': 'G'}, {'E': 'E'}]}
count = 0
for k,v in dict.items():
    for ele in v:
        for key, val in ele.items():
            print(count, k, "\t", key, "\t", val)
            count += 1
```

Sample output:

```
0 bar    F   G  
1 bar    E   E  
2 foo    H   C  
3 foo    D   E  
4 foo    F   G
```

Comment: Thanks +1 for answer if I cant get any pandas answer I will use and accept this.